Erasing raster cell using another raster that overlaps in ArcMap
I have 2 raster datasets

one is methane data
and the other is cloud cover data.

What im trying to do is to remove methane data that overlaps with cloud cover data. I've tried the SetNull tool (Value = 1) but I keep getting the wrong result.
Is there something wrong with my method or is there any other alternative?

Have you followed the instructions for the setnull correctly? In your limited text it's not possible to determine if you have set false raster. Screen shots always help. Suggest you edit your question and add more explanation.

@Hornbydd okay ill try provide screenshots probably try to use the SetNull correctly
